# how to rotate an image by "alpha" degrees in java language

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a function **public static int[][][] rotate_alpha(int[][][] im,double alpha)** which i have to use to rotate the image.
the problem is im not able to find a soultion on how to do it with a given 3d array
i have rotated the image 90 degrees but couldnt do it with a given degree(alpha)
my code for 90 degrees rotation is:

```
    **int[][] res = new int[this.frame[0].length][this.frame.length];
    //Transpose
    for (int i = 0; i < this.frame[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.frame.length; j++) {
            res[i][j] = this.frame[this.frame.length - 1 - j][i];
        }
    }
    //copying res to the matrix array
    frame = res;**
```

[image: this is an example on how to do it]

Comment: Instead of asking this again, you should instead edit your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70171642/how-to-rotate-an-image-by-a-given-degree-in-java-language) to include the details you were asked about.

Comment: sorry im new i will delete my previous question

Comment: and no what im looking for is a 3d array to rotate